# showing more than 1 slide in ion-slider

Tags: ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic3 project. I want to use slider component. By default it only shows a single image at a time. Is it possible to show 3 images on a single page. and when user swipe new 3 and so on.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: do you want to use this:https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/

Comment: yes, i want to use this, but having 3 images at one time

Comment: Then put your 3 images in each slide... a slide is basically an HTML container, you put what you want inside, not only images actually. Can you share with us your slide code so we can help effectively?

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-3mpvqk?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

Answer (score 1):

Its  slidesPerView='3', which I am looking for. It shows desired number of items at one time on screen.